# The presence of both operator == and operator != breaks some concepts

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-concepts, comparison-operators

After upgrading to latest Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6, one of our custom views stopped to be recognized as `std::ranges::range`. It turned out that the problem was in the presence of both `operator ==` and `operator !=` in the view's iterator.

Please find below minimal simplified example (without views and iterators already):

```
struct A {
    friend bool operator ==( const A &, const A & ) = default;
};

struct B {
    friend bool operator ==( const B &, const B & ) = default;
    friend bool operator ==( const B &, const A & ) { return false; }
    // Visual Studio 2022 version 17.6 does not like next line
    friend bool operator !=( const B &, const A & ) { return true; }
};

template< class T, class U >
concept comparable =
  requires(const std::remove_reference_t<T>& t,
           const std::remove_reference_t<U>& u) {
    { t == u } -> std::same_as<bool>;
    { t != u } -> std::same_as<bool>;
    { u == t } -> std::same_as<bool>;
    { u != t } -> std::same_as<bool>;
  };
  
// ok in GCC, Clang and Visual Studio before version 17.6
static_assert( comparable<A, B> );
```

The example is accepted by GCC and Clang, but not the latest Visual Studio, which prints the error:

```
<source>(25): error C2607: static assertion failed
<source>(25): note: the concept 'comparable<A,B>' evaluated to false
<source>(18): note: 'bool operator ==(const B &,const A &)': rewritten candidate function was excluded from overload resolution because a corresponding operator!= declared in the same scope
<source>(4): note: could be 'bool operator ==(const A &,const A &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
<source>(8): note: or       'bool operator ==(const B &,const B &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
<source>(9): note: or       'bool operator ==(const B &,const A &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
<source>(4): note: or 'bool operator ==(const A &,const A &)' [synthesized expression 'y == x']
<source>(8): note: or 'bool operator ==(const B &,const B &)' [synthesized expression 'y == x']
<source>(9): note: or 'bool operator ==(const B &,const A &)' [synthesized expression 'y == x']
<source>(18): note: 'bool operator ==(const B &,const A &)': rewritten candidate function was excluded from overload resolution because a corresponding operator!= declared in the same scope
<source>(18): note: while trying to match the argument list '(const A, const B)'
```

Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/evTfofq3d

Is it a bug in new Visual Studio compiler, or on the contrary the others are wrong?

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) says `For equality operator expressions x == y and x != y, a synthesized candidate with the order of the two parameters reversed is added for each member, non-member, and built-in operator==s found, unless there is a matching operator!=.` so maybe that's being interpreted as `==(const B &,const A &)` isn't generated because `!=( const B &, const A & )` isn't present?

Comment: Reduced https://godbolt.org/z/Yeevchxr6

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is a result of The Equality Operator You Are Looking For
([P2468](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2468r2.html)).

The comparison changes in C++20 - which allow `a == b` and `a != b` to find rewritten and synthesized candidates - can break a lot of C++17 code. You can see some examples in the paper.

In an effort to mitigate those breaks (not all, but at least most), Cameron DaCamara<sup>†</sup>, an MSVC compiler developer, came up with a narrow rule that attempts to use the C++17 comparison rules for C++17-ish code. Basically, in C++20, there's no need to write `operator!=` since the existing `operator==` will be good enough (`a != b` can use the rewritten expression `!(a == b)`, which is almost always what you want, so why bother writing that?). But in C++17, we didn't have this rule yet, so you *had* to write both.

Thus, the proposed rule is as follows: if we find an `operator==` and an `operator!=` in the same scope with the same parameters, use the C++17 rules. Otherwise, use the C++20 rules. This is one of those C++ rules that I kind of hoped that nobody needed to know about - your C++17 code just continues to work fine, and your new C++20 code would just work to begin with.

---

Using the posted reduced example:

```cpp
struct A { };

struct B {
  friend bool operator==(const B &, const A &);
  friend bool operator!=(const B &, const A &);
};

int main() {
  return A{} == B{};
}
```

In C++17, this doesn't compile, because there's no viable operator.

In C++20, before the paper I'm talking about, this would evaluate as `B{} == A{}`. But in C++20, with the resolution of this DR, because you're providing both `operator==` and `operator!=` and they're the same, we assume that you wanted the C++17 rules, so we're back to this not compiling, because we don't consider the rewritten candidate.

The fix is simply to not provide that operator:

```cpp
struct A { };

struct B {
  friend bool operator==(const B &, const A &);
};

int main() {
  return A{} == B{};
}
```

Or, if you need to handle both C++17/C++20, then that one isn't enough anyway, since you need to provide three others - all conditionally:

```cpp
struct A { };

struct B {
  friend bool operator==(const B&, const A&);
#if !(defined(__cpp_impl_three_way_comparison) and __cpp_impl_three_way_comparison >= 201907)
  friend bool operator!=(const B& b, const A& a) { return !(b == a); }
  friend bool operator==(const A& a, const B& b) { return b == a; }
  friend bool operator!=(const A& a, const B& b) { return !(b == a); }
#endif
};

int main() {
  return A{} == B{};
}
```

---

As an update, this is [CWG 2804](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2804.html), which points out that the specific wording from P2468 didn't quite cover the intent correctly and doesn't handle `friend` operators in the way you might expect. From the issue:

```cpp
struct X {
  operator int();
  friend bool operator==(X, int);
  friend bool operator!=(X, int);  // #1
} x;

bool bx = x == x;    // error: lookup for rewrite target determination does not find hidden friend #1

struct Y {
  operator int();
  friend bool operator==(Y, int);   // #2
} y;

bool operator!=(Y, int);            // #3

bool by = y == y;                   // OK, #2 is not a rewrite target because lookup finds #3
```

Arguably the intent is that `bx` should be ok (we should not consider rewrites in this situation because `operator==` and `operator!=` were declared together) and `by` should be an error (because we should consider rewrites in this case, and consider rewrites leads to ambiguity).

---

<sup>†</sup> Technically there are 9 other authors listed on this paper besides Cameron, including me, but Cameron did the bulk of the work here, with him and Richard Smith coming up with the final rule set. To the extent that I had meaningful involvement in the paper, it was that I was the one who broke the code that necessitated the fix to begin with. So given that Cameron came up with this design, and tested it against a lot of existing code, it's not surprising that MSVC is the first compiler to implement the new rule.

Comment: In light of duck's answer, is there a wording issue in P2468? duck argues that the "search" that's done in this context won't find a hidden friend.

Comment: @BrianBi Yeah, that's the CWG issue I just updated the answer with.

Answer (score 9):

After [P2468](https://wg21.link/p2468), an `operator==` function is not used for rewritten comparisons if a matching `operator!=` can be found by a search in the same scope.

MSVC appears to interpret the wording of the standard on this feature differently from GCC/Clang.

[[over.match.oper]/3.4.4](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#3.4.4):

> - For the equality operators, the rewritten candidates also include a synthesized candidate, with the order of the two parameters reversed, for each non-rewritten candidate for the expression `y == x` that is a rewrite target with first operand `y`.

[[over.match.oper]/4](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#4.sentence-1):

> A non-template function or function template `F` named `operator==` is a rewrite target with first operand `o` unless **a search** for the name `operator!=` in the scope *S* from the instantiation context of the operator expression finds a function or function template that would correspond to `F` if its name were `operator==`, where *S* is the scope of the class type of `o` if `F` is a class member, and the namespace scope of which `F` is a member otherwise.

A *search* for a name in a scope (as defined in [[class.member.lookup]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.member.lookup#1)) finds only the declarations bound to that name in that scope ([[basic.lookup.general]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.general#3.sentence-1)). Friend declarations do not bind names ([[dcl.meaning.general]/2.1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning.general#2.1)), so `friend operator!=(const B&, const A&)` should not prevent `operator==(const B&, const A&)` from being a rewritten candidate for `A() == B()` (at least under a literal interpretation of this rule, which seems to be what GCC and Clang implement):

```cpp
struct A {};
struct B {
    friend bool operator==(B, A);
    friend bool operator!=(B, A);
};
bool x = A() == B(); // OK in GCC/Clang
bool operator!=(B, A);
bool y = A() == B(); // error in GCC/Clang
```