# C++20, Rewritten candidate function was excluded from overload resolution because a corresponding operator!= declared in the same scope with

Tags: c++, g++, c++20, visual-studio-2022

This code doesn't compile since VS 2022 17.6, but does compile with latest g++. See godbolt:
https://godbolt.org/z/Gvn84qK7n.
In what way could I rewrite the code such that in compiles pre VS2022 17.6, and post?

```cpp
template<class T>
struct Property {
    operator const T&() const           { return value;              }      
    bool operator==(const T &val) const { return this->value == val; }
    bool operator!=(const T &val) const { return this->value != val; }    
    T value;
};

int main() {
    enum class Foo {Red, Green};
    Property<Foo> a;   
    Foo e;

    bool comp2 = e == a;
    bool comp3 = e != a;
}
```

I tried reversing the order of the comparison in the client code, that seems to work:

```
    bool comp2 = a == e;
    bool comp3 = a != e;
```

Comment: Can you add a non-member function? `template<class T>
bool operator==( const T& left, const Property<T> &right ) {
    return right == left;
}`

Comment: This seems to be caused by the rules which are listed and explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76289350/the-presence-of-both-operator-and-operator-breaks-some-concepts) thread.

Comment: Given what's written in the duplicate Q&A, MSVC is correct, so remove `operator!=`. If you need it to work pre C++20, only define it if compiling in pre C++20 mode.

Comment: ChrisMM's answer (and also the operator!=  non-member function solved my issue.

Comment: @MichielJaspers Why not simply remove it completely?